# Python - finding the number of items in one line

Tags: python

I have generated a list of itemsets which look like this:

```
('chicken',)  
('mango',)  
('chicken', 'apple')  
('chicken', 'rice')  
('chicken', 'beer')  
('mango', 'apple')  
('chicken', 'rice', 'apple')  
('beer', 'apple', 'chicken')  
('beer', 'rice', 'chicken')  
('beer', 'apple', 'chicken', 'rice')  
('rice',)  
('rice', 'apple')  
('beer', 'rice')  
('beer', 'rice', 'apple')  
('beer', 'apple')  
('apple',)
```

I want to know how to find the number of items in each line using python. can anyone suggest a method to do this?

Comment: How did you create this? It does not look like a python list. Is it saved in a text file or are the tuples really part of a python list?

Comment: can you format your code and assign the data to a list?

Comment: no it is not a python list. this is a candidate itemset generated from apriori algorithm's implemenation in python on which i have been working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the the tuples are in a list you can do the following:

```
 map(len,TupleLst)
```

if it is a text file:

```
f.open("document")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
map(lambda x: len(eval(x)),lines)
```

Comment: If your question is answered you can close it by putting it on green  ;)

Answer (score 1):

The below code is simple and written in pythonic way.

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:

    for line in f.readlines():
        print len(line.strip()[1:-1].split(', '))
```

Using **with** makes the file auto-close at the end of the block.

Read all lines from the file and iterate over them using for loop.

**line.strip()** removes the leading and tailing spaces.

"('chicken',)  " --> "('chicken',)"

indexing the result removes parenthesis

"('chicken',)" --> "'chicken',"

now the string can be split using **,**.

Comment: Thank you. This helped a lot